# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for python object

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error in my code. I am attempting to make a maze solver and I am getting an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parseMaze.py", line 29, in <module>
    m = maze()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am attempting to create a `maze` object called `m` but apparently I'm doing something wrong.

I wrote these lines in `parseMaze.py`

```
#!/user/bin/env python

import sys
import cell
import maze
import array

# open file and parse characters
with open(sys.argv[-1]) as f:
# local variables
  x = 0 # x length
  y = 0 # y length
  char = [] # array to hold the character through maze
  iCell = []# not sure if I need
# go through file
  while True:
    c = f.read(1)
    if not c:
      break
    char.append(c)
    if c == '\n':
      y += 1
    if c != '\n':
      x += 1
  print y
  x = x/y
  print x

  m = maze()
  m.setDim(x,y)
  for i in range (len(char)):
    if char(i) == ' ':
      m.addCell(i, 0)
    elif char(i) == '%':
      m.addCell(i, 1)
    elif char(i) == 'P':
      m.addCell(i, 2)
    elif char(i) == '.':
      m.addCell(i, 3)
    else:
      print "do newline"
  print str(m.cells)
```

Here is my `maze.py` file which contains the maze class:

```
#! /user/bin/env python

class maze:

  w = 0
  h = 0
  size = 0
  cells =[]

# width and height variables of the maze
  def _init_(self):
    w = 0
    h = 0
    size = 0
    cells =[]


# set dimensions of maze
  def _init_(self, width, height):
    self.w = width
    self.w = height
    self.size = width*height

# find index based off row major order
  def findRowMajor(self, x, y):
    return (y*w)+x

# add a cell to the maze
  def addCell(self, index, state):
    cells.append(cell(index, state))
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 39):

It should be `maze.maze()` instead of `maze()`.

Or you could change your `import` statement to `from maze import maze`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the first maze referencing the file and the second referencing the class?

Comment: @user2604504 Yes. But to technically it's referencing the `module` (that got constructed with the content of the file),  not the `file`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the import statement, you can only import a class not module.
'import maze' is wrong rather use
'from maze import maze'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have overridden the builtin function/variable "module" by setting the global variable "module".
just print the module see whats in it.