# How to: setting a testsuite in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I know it is a bit silly question, but using links provides below, I am still unable to create testsuite.

I have now two test cases (there will be much more), let assume that the name of there are:

```
class step1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_case1(self):
[...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

and:

```
class step2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_case2(self):
[...]

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

I want to create other file .py file: testsuite, which can aggregate  test_case1, test_case2, test_case3...

I tried something like that, for example:

```
import unittest
import step1
import step2


def suite():
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.step1(test_case1))
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.step2(test_case2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

> Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'step1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`addTest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.addTest) and pass `TestCase` instance to it, you also miss `return` statement:

```
def suite():
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(step1())
    test_suite.addTest(step2())
    return test_suite
```

or, in one line using [`addTests()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.addTests):

```
test_suite.addTests([step1(), step2()])
```

Comment: Probalby it is better, but still getting: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'addTest'

Comment: @ti01878 oops, sure, fixed the mistake. Thanks. Note that the code assumes `step1`, `step2` are test cases.

Comment: Well, my code was so bad that I have to do 2 things more: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087189/python-unittest-testcase-object-has-no-attribute-runtest and 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928826/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-for-python-object, but finnaly it works :) Thank you.